# MATPLOTLIB: How can I align my two X-axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just can't figure out how to align my two X-axes since I'm using the same xticks array for both. I want to display the date at the top and the time at the bottom axis, but the two axes are missaligned. The data I'm using is 2601 lines long. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

f = open("data.txt", "r")
#data.txt data in each line
#HistoricalData. 4001 - Time: 20191115  20:37:00, Open: 70.185, High: 70.195, Low: 70.135, Close: 70.14, Volume: -1, Count: -1, WAP: -1s

my_list = []
my_list_real = np.array([])
my_list_time = np.array([])
counter = 0
for x in f:
    my_list.append(x)
    counter += 1
print(counter)

i = 0
while i < len(my_list):
    start = my_list[i].find("Open")
    start += 6
    end = my_list[i].find(", High")
    end -= 0
    variable = my_list[i][start:end]
    my_list_real = np.append(my_list_real, float(variable))

    start = my_list[i].find("Time: ")
    start += 6
    end = start + 8

    variable_time = my_list[i][start:end] + " " + my_list[i][(end+2):(end+10)]
    datetime_object = datetime.strptime(variable_time, '%Y%m%d %X')
    my_list_time = np.append(my_list_time, datetime_object)
    i += 1

number_array = np.arange(len(my_list_time))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

string_array = my_list_time.astype('str')
plt.xticks(number_array, string_array)

ax.plot(number_array, my_list_real)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5, min_n_ticks=5))
ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.set_xticks(number_array, minor=False)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(5, min_n_ticks=5))
ax2.set_xticklabels(string_array, fontdict=None, minor=False)
ax2.set_xticks(np.linspace(ax2.get_xticks()[0], ax2.get_xticks()[-1], len(ax.get_xticks())))

ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='Price ($)',
    title='INTC')
ax.grid()
fig.savefig("test.png")

plt.show()
```

Here is my output:

[image]

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Either set x limits for the upper axis or you could plot it again on the second axis with the extra parameter (alpha=0) which would make the second line completely transparent. The problem is that you're not doing anything currently with the second x-axis, so it doesn't know what the new x-limits should be.

Comment: Thank you! I tried adding ax2.plot(number_array, my_list_real) to my code just now. The first value is properly aligned now, but the rest is still not in place. Do you maybe know how to fix the rest?

Comment: I believe the problem now is that you are doing additional actions to ax2 but not to ax. I would only plot on ax2, then keep the set_major_locator, and get rid of the other manipulations. Let me know if this fixes your issue. If it does, accept the answer, so others having the same issue can find the "answered" question.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify shared x- or y- axis explicitly via `ax.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax, ax2)`

for example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(label='a')
ax2 = ax.twiny()

ax.get_shared_x_axes().join(ax, ax2)

ax.plot([0,2,5.5], c='r')
ax2.plot([1,3,5,6], c='g')
```

you might also want to have a look at `ax.secondary_xaxis('top')`
(since you only want the labels and not actually a second axis for plotting right?)